# Meme-controlled people

Tags: story-identification

AI uses memes to control people. Part of a number of stories by John Barnes? One story has a bunch of meme-controlled mercenaries who capture a girls' school and 'serb' and kill all the residents. Read it back in the 00s.

Comment: Wait, a society run by memes? This isn't non-fiction?

Comment: @Adamant In this case a "meme" is a kind of malware that is able to jump "operating system boundaries" well enough to treat human begins as just another platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost certainly this is one of the [Meme Wars](https://us.macmillan.com/series/memewars/) series of books by John Barnes. Your description doesn't actually give enough info to positively identify *which* of the books it is, but it's most likely to be [Kaleidoscope Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleidoscope_Century). The protagonist talks about seizing a sorority house in the name of its meme deity and proceeding to rape (or "serb") the prettiest girls.

> That had been fun; Fargo Dome hadn’t been hit significantly before,
>   and the loot was terrific. Not to mention Sadi and I had grabbed one
>   whole sorority house at the University of North Dakota, turned the
>   ugly ones over to One True and spent three days serbing the pretty
>   ones before Murphy called the unit back in and we had to hang all of
>   them.

Comment: Ah, so the SCP Foundation *did* steal this idea from somewhere!